# Access most recent component's routing from other component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a problem with `react-router` library. Please, look at my simplified routing:

```
<Router>
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
        <Route path="assets" component={Assets}>
            <Route path=":id/definition" component={AssetDefinition}>
                { /* etc. ... */ }
            </Route>
            <Route path=":id/version" component={AssetVersion}>
                <Route path=":verId/edit" component={EditVersion}></Route>
                { /* etc. ... */ }
            </Route>
        </Route>
        <Route path="applications" component={Applications}>
            <Route path=":id/definition" component={AppDefinition}>
                { /* etc. ... */ }
            </Route>
            <Route path=":id/version" component={AppVersion}>
                { /* etc. ... */ }
            </Route>
        </Route>
    </Route>
</Router>
```

In `Layout` component I render `Menu` next to `this.props.children` rendered basing on routing. My `Menu` is being generated dynamically using `this.props.route.path`.

```
export default class Layout extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Menu />    
                { this.props.children }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The problem is I don't know the appropriate routing path in `Menu`.

**e.g.**
I open `/assets/123/version`. Now I want to check `AssetVersion` component's route children (from `this.props.route.childRoutes`). I expect children elements inside this route (basing on given routing). But what I get is `assets` and `applications`, because `Menu` is higher and "fixed" in components tree.

How to access the most recent component's routing open in my app inside the `Menu`?

Comment: When you say "the most recent routing open", do you mean the current one?

Comment: If I have path `/assets/123/version/1.0/edit` (I expanded routing a little), I need the routing state of .../edit (let's say `EditVersion` component). But remember I need it in my `Menu`.